# Nginx displaying HTML code in browser when running .PHP file

Tags: php, html, nginx, webserver

When I run this code

```
<html>
<head> 
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <?php
        header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
        $html = file_get_contents('https://api.com/auth');
        $json = json_decode($html,true);     
        $token= $json['token'];  
        $postdata = http_build_query(array('token' => $token));                          

        $opts = array('http' =>array('method'=>'POST','header'=>'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded','content'=>$postdata));                       
        $context = stream_context_create($opts);
        // display results
        $result=file_get_contents('https://api.com/api-mc', null, $context);                                
        $json_result = json_decode($result,true);
        echo $json_result["USD"]["SELL"];
   ?>
</body>
</html>
```

In a .php file in my local php server (on os x terminal "php -S localhost:9000"), it displays correctly only the output of the PHP code. But when I run it through NGINX on a Digital Ocean server, it displays the correct output of the PHP code, but it also displays the html tags itself. The HTML is not being interpreted. I suspect the problem is in my NGINX configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/example;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: inspect the page source to verify that it's not html-escaping the uploaded html, press ctrl+u and look to see if there are a bunch of html escaped &gt; &lt; entities around the code.

Comment: There's a couple of major problems with your code. 1. You're trying to display a HTML page, but your trying to set the content type with `header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');` which sets the content type to Json. 2. You're trying to set a header _after_ you've already outputted content. All headers must be sent  _before_ anything is outputted to the client.

Comment: That was it, thank you Magnus. Thank you also Dash for your answer.